# Is there a way to do Bubble Sort algorithm in Ruby using a while loop with an any method?

Tags: ruby, bubble-sort, enumerable

I'm trying to use a while loop with an any enumerable to optimize the Bubble Sort algorithm, but having trouble figuring out a way to make it work. Right now, I'm getting an error, but I want to know if conceptually I'm on the right track?

I've attached a few examples that the code should return for better context.

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
    while arr.any? { |ele, idx| ele > arr[idx + 1] }
        if arr[idx] > arr[idx + 1]
            arr[idx], arr[idx + 1] = arr[idx + 1], arr[idx]
        end
    end
    return arr
end

p bubble_sort([2, 8, 5, 2, 6])      # => [2, 2, 5, 6, 8]
p bubble_sort([10, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3])  # => [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10]
```

Comment: the `if` condition is correct, but the `while loop` is not

Comment: I'm not familiar with an `any?` method which accepts a block taking two arguments (element and index, apparently). What class is that defined in, please?

Comment: To "optimize" bubble sort makes no sense - for most data sets it's the least optimal algorithm available.   Using "any" would require partitioning the array in some way which would make the whole thing even worse.

Comment: @MichaelChaney - you should implement [BogoSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort), if for no other reason that to demonstrate to yourself that Bubble Sort is not the least optimal algorithm. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  sorted = false
  while !sorted
    did_a_swap = false
    arr.each_index do |idx|
      next unless arr[idx + 1]
      if arr[idx] > arr[idx + 1]
        did_a_swap = true
        arr[idx], arr[idx + 1] = arr[idx + 1], arr[idx]
      end
    end
    sorted = !did_a_swap
  end
  return arr
end

p bubble_sort([2, 8, 5, 2, 6])      # => [2, 2, 5, 6, 8]
p bubble_sort([10, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3])  # => [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10]
```

If you accept that you do a full pass through of the array every time there is at least one unsorted pair, then you can use `while !sorted` and define `sorted` as *was there zero swaps this run*?

Comment: The bubble sort is called bubble sort because in each pass-through, the highest unsorted value “bubbles” up to its correct position. Instead of iterating through all the elements inside the while loop using each_with_index, we can make use of it and only loop through the unsorted elements. please check the gist: https://gist.github.com/shanshaji/5da49d1177cdf1cdc981f3dacc005b56

Answer (score 1):

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  length = arr.length

  (0..length-2).each do |i|
    (0..(length-i-2)).each do |j|
      if arr[j] > arr[j+1]
        arr[j+1], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[j+1]
      end
    end
  end

  arr
end
```

Comment: Ohhhh a nested do block, that's really elegant, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def bubble_sort(array)
    array_length = array.length
    return array if array_length <= 1
    unsorted_until_index = array_length - 1
    sorted = false
    until sorted
        sorted = true
        for i in (0..unsorted_until_index)
            if array[i+1]
                if array[i] > array[i+1]
                    array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
                    sorted = false
                end
            end
        end
        unsorted_until_index -= 1
    end
    return array
end
```

I saw lots of answers where everyone is iterating or looping the length of the array inside the while loop. The bubble sort is called bubble sort because in each pass-through, the highest unsorted value “bubbles” up to its correct position. So that those elements can be omitted in the upcoming while loop. And instead of until, `while !sorted` can be used.